# node scheduler destroy task on node server crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduled-tasks

I make an application in which i used node server for webServices. my application have feature to book flight & movie ticket & bus ticket & many more..

i need to send reminder message to user for their booking just before 2 hours of user's flight / bus time / movie / etc...

so i use [Node-Scheduler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) it allow you to set this kind of dynamic cron jobs..

i use linux server on rent (i haven't cloud) and use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) module / package.

now what forever do is whenever my node-server crash.. it will restart it automatically.. and if node-server crash then my node-scheduler cron job is destroy scheduler job.

i'm using mySql database. so,...

Is there any solution to solve this issue??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store your timer job details in the DB/or a file,
and use a transaction approach to create/manage timer jobs.

Upon server start, load the jobs from file/DB.
This should keep things consistent.

For more robustness you should run your scheduling application code out of the node-server as a separate process, this way your scheduler won't go down with your node server app.

For a high level of scalable robustness, try connecting your services(scheduler and webservice) as microservices, maybe using a microservice toolkit like SenecaJS.

Comment: i got your point, but if another process ( or node server set on another port specially for scheduler) will crash then it will be the same.. one more thing we need to consider here that we should check db continuously if we store schedule in db and need to check that job scheduler which time had past and not run fetch that booking and run a reminder function, but i think this is not a way to proceed, and ya new process (separate port / server) is good idea but that will not work too in case of that perticuler server crash..

Comment: When you said node-server crash i took it as your node application Crashing because of some issues. Not your linux machine crashing because of some issues.
Of course, when the server goes down,everything on it would go down too. But you'd have to do distributed microservices to deal with such kind of failures.